# How to insert content of special tag in string into array using php?

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have string:

```
$strings = "<p>text123456:2342345234 </p>
<p>exampletextasdasdasd::tesastasdasd </p>
<p>gov:eeeass@mmm</p>"
```

How I can convert these strings to array?

I need get output:

```
["text123456:2342345234", "exampletextasdasdasd::tesastasdasd", "gov:eeeass@mmm"]
```

My code:

```
$array = explode(' ', $strings);
```

Is not working..

Comment: Where do you get that string from?

Comment: Steps you'll need to do: strip the `<p></p>` tags, `explode` on new line. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using regex `/<p>([^<]+)<\/p>/` you can get any text between `<p></p>` in provided string. Use the regex in `preg_match()`.

```
preg_match_all("/<p>([^<]+)<\/p>/", $strings, $matches);
print_r($matches[1])
```

Result

```
Array
(
    [0] => text123456:2342345234 
    [1] => exampletextasdasdasd::tesastasdasd 
    [2] => gov:eeeass@mmm
 )
```

If you want to remove additional space at the end of strings, you can use `/<p>(\S+)\s?<\/p>/` pattern instead or use combination of `trim()` and `array_map()`

```
$res = array_map('trim', $matches[1]);
```

Check result in [demo](https://3v4l.org/DZE9r)

Comment: On end string your have spaces, can delete please?

Comment: @Dumitru Space is in end of every tag but if you want to remove it you can use `/<p>(\S+)\s?<\/p>/` instead

Answer (score 0):

try the following...

```
$strings = "<p>text123456:2342345234 </p><p>exampletextasdasdasd::tesastasdasd </p><p>gov:eeeass@mmm</p>";

$strings = str_replace('<p>', '', $strings);

$array = explode('</p>', $strings);

/* to trim the strings */
$array = array_map(function($string){ return trim($string); }, $array);
```

Comment: Striptags will remove the tags. Probably cleaner and easier to read also